# Dimensions of the intersection of 8 quadrics

Tags: quadrics, algebraic-systems

Suppose $e_i,q_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $1\leq i \leq 3$ with $\Vert e_i \Vert=1$ are known.

Define the projection on the plane orthogonal to $e_i$

$P_i= I-e_i e_i^T$ where $I$ is the $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ identity matrix.

Suppose to have the unknowns $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $e_i^T u \neq 0$, and the following system of equations

$u^T v=0$

$\Vert u \Vert= 1$.

$k  e_i \times u + P_i v e_i^T u -q_i e_i^T u =0 $ for $1\leq i \leq 3$.

Each $k  e_i \times u + P_i v e_i^T u -q_i e_i^T u =0 $ provides three equations, but only two are linearly independent. The system has therefore 8 equations (8 quadrics).

There are clearly sets of $q_i$ for which the system has no solution (it is sufficient to take any $q_i$ such that $e_i^T q_i \neq 0$). Is there any choice of the $q_i$ such that the system has multiple solutions in $k$,$u$,$v$?

Another way of formulating the question is the following. Given constants $e_i, e_i\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $P_i= I-e_i e_i^T$, is the following function $(k,u,v) \rightarrow (q1,q2,q3)$ injective?

$\displaystyle q_i = k \frac{e_i \times u}{e_i^T u} + P_i v $